# Android SafetyNet API fails when using API key restriction

Tags: android, google-play-services, safetynet

When setting restriction to an API key the Attestation API stops working:
`OnFailureListener` gets fired with the [`CANCELLED`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#CANCELED)(16) status code

The restrictions are the android package name and the certificate signature(SHA-1)

[image]

Does the SafetyNet Attestation API support restricted API keys ?

Note: the same API key with the additional restriction works fine with Google Maps API

**UPDATE:**
On devices running Google Play Services v13.0 and above, the SafetyNet Attestation API also supports app-restricted API keys.
https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068393/safety-environment-check-in-android-using-safetynet-attestation-api-is-not-worki). You might be restricting the key to the wrong package name. Try to recheck the API key or create a new one like in this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html#add-api-key).

Comment: @abielita, double checked the package name and created the new one - still doesn't work. Also that key works fine with the Maps API

Comment: A quick question, Did you enable the service ?

Comment: What are all the restrictions you're using?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, yes the service is enabled and everything works without the restrictions

Comment: @YvetteColomb, the restrictions I'm using are the package name and the hash of the certificate which was used to sign the apk, I didn't set the API restriction

Comment: Just wild guessing it works on release but not on debug?

Comment: @rekire neither debug nor release works for me

Comment: Can you add a code snip it how you implemented that?

Comment: @rekire I tried it with the official sample and the behavior is the same https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet/blob/master/client/java/SafetyNetSample/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/safetynetsample/SafetyNetSampleFragment.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've contacted a friend of mine at Google, and he reached out to their team. This is currently not supported - there's no way to get this API restricted with the SHA1 fingerprint. It's on their internal roadmap to accommodate this, but for now it won't work.

If you go to their [quota request page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/safetynetqr) you can see that they specifically say not to use any form of API key restrictions.

Comment: And I'm replying here mainly because we ran into the same problem in our app today.

Comment: Hi Carl, thank you for the insights, the bounty is yours :) I didn't notice that they say not to use the restrictions. Looks like we need to find some ways to protect our api key from not being compromised

Comment: IMHO! If something like that is there, they should have added it in their document not on quota request page. I mean Nobody would check that out unless they need more requests.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: I'm not sure and no longer work on an app using Safetynet.

Comment: API key restriction has been enabled for SafetyNet API keys @MickeyTin