# How do I get Android SafetyNetClient.Attest to work with an API key that's restricted to android apps?

Tags: android, google-play-services, safetynet

I call: `mSafetyNetClient.attest(nonce, apiKey)`

and I send in my nonce and API Key. Basically it seems to only work when I have the API Key unrestricted. If I restrict it to only android apps, it stops working.

Why is that and how do I get it to work with android apps restriction?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: AFAIK, this should work even if it is restricted to android app. As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation#add-api-key) there is no indication that it will not work if the API key is set to Android specific access. You may want to create another API key following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup) to verify what is wrong. Also you may want to check the log for any suspicious behavior. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot weird it's working for maps when I restrict to an app built in debug mode. Should being in debug mode or release mode affect the safetnet api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer that I found on a similarly asked question. Enjoy! :)

I've contacted a friend of mine at Google, and he reached out to their team. This is currently not supported - there's no way to get this API restricted with the SHA1 fingerprint. It's on their internal roadmap to accommodate this, but for now it won't work.

If you go to their [quota request page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/safetynetqr) you can see that they specifically say not to use any form of API key restrictions.

SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50360510/8091409