# Safetynet Issue Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}

Tags: android, safetynet

We have follow [Scottyab Safetynet Library](https://github.com/scottyab/safetynethelper/blob/master/sample/build.gradle).

We are facing error of “**Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}**” event though 4G internet connectivity available in our android device with package name **com.safetynet.sample** where as sample project is working fine with package name **com.scottyab.safetynet.sample**. We have check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068393/safety-environment-check-in-android-using-safetynet-attestation-api-is-not-worki) but not work.

Below code where we have facing this issue

```
private void runSafetyNetTest() {
    Log.v(TAG, "running SafetyNet.API Test");
    requestNonce = generateOneTimeRequestNonce();
    requestTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    writeLog("running SafetyNet.API Test");
    SafetyNet.SafetyNetApi.attest(googleApiClient, requestNonce)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onResult(final SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult result) {
                                       writeLog("running SafetyNet.API Result");
                                   //result = Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null} 
                                       if (!validateResultStatus(result)) {
                                           return;
                                       }

                                       final String jwsResult = result.getJwsResult();
                                       final SafetyNetResponse response = parseJsonWebSignature(jwsResult);
                                       lastResponse = response;
                                       writeLog("Res :: " + response);

                                       //validate payload of the response
                                       if (validateSafetyNetResponsePayload(response)) {
                                           if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(googleDeviceVerificationApiKey)) {
                                               //if the api key is set, run the AndroidDeviceVerifier
                                               AndroidDeviceVerifier androidDeviceVerifier = new AndroidDeviceVerifier(googleDeviceVerificationApiKey, jwsResult);
                                               androidDeviceVerifier.verify(new AndroidDeviceVerifier.AndroidDeviceVerifierCallback() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void error(String errorMsg) {
                                                       callback.error(RESPONSE_ERROR_VALIDATING_SIGNATURE, "Response signature validation error: " + errorMsg);
                                                   }

                                                   @Override
                                                   public void success(boolean isValidSignature) {
                                                       if (isValidSignature) {
                                                           callback.success(response.isCtsProfileMatch(), response.isBasicIntegrity());
                                                       } else {
                                                           callback.error(RESPONSE_FAILED_SIGNATURE_VALIDATION, "Response signature invalid");

                                                       }
                                                   }
                                               });
                                           } else {
                                               Log.w(TAG, "No google Device Verification ApiKey defined");
                                               callback.error(RESPONSE_FAILED_SIGNATURE_VALIDATION_NO_API_KEY, "No Google Device Verification ApiKey defined. Marking as failed. SafetyNet CtsProfileMatch: " + response.isCtsProfileMatch());
                                           }
                                       } else {
                                           callback.error(RESPONSE_VALIDATION_FAILED, "Response payload validation failed");
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

            );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be related to the fact that the attestation API has been marked as deprecated. The new one doesn't depend on the google client API, you should check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation). Also Google released an example app using the new api, you can check [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet).

Comment: I've copied the code from the example and get this `NETWORK_ERROR`. Probably it is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this discussion](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet/issues/10), the wrong `API_KEY` may be the reason for the error.